# Spring Config Server encrypting issue of "=" sign

Tags: spring, encryption, spring-boot, configserver

Can anyone experience problem while encrypting through config server with values having special characters?

Currently I am doing this

```
curl http://localhost:8888/configser/config/encrypt -d eF345edo=
```

I also referred this https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/620 and tried as below

```
curl http://localhost:8888/configser/config/encrypt --data-urlencode eF345edo=
```

But still no success in encrypting that **'='** sign.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you encouter [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Output_Padding)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At the end I got work around from the official document of spring cloud config: (See the TIP area for special characters)
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_encryption_and_decryption

curl command to get the final result:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/plain" http://localhost:8888/configser/config/encrypt -d eF345edo=
```

Thanks @Bond - Java Bond

Thanks everyone for help.